# What is wrong with my Python code on codecademy?

Tags: python, if-statement, arguments, function

I am currently learning Python on codecademy and I am stuck. These are the directions:

> Below your existing code, define a function called `rental_car_cost`
>   with an argument called `days`. Calculate the cost of renting the car:
>   Every day you rent the car costs $40. if you rent the car for 7 or
>   more days, you get $50 off your total. Alternatively (`elif`), if you
>   rent the car for 3 or more days, you get $20 off your total. You
>   cannot get both of the above discounts. Return that cost.

The following is the code I have:

```
def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
        cost -= 50

    elif days >= 3:
        cost -= 20

    return cost
```

When I try to save and submit that code, it gives me this error:

> Oops, try again. Did you create a function called rental_car_cost?

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: your function looks fine. The instructions do say "Below your existing code...". Is there any other code that you should submit as well?

Comment: Add an else to that function

Comment: And also watch out for indentation

Comment: After seeing many questions here from people having trouble with Codecademy, I checked it out and verified that it is, indeed, bad.

Comment: As I've already stated, the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html) is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the function definition is below the function call.
You should put the above snippet above the function call.

**For Example** Below written code will give you an error as the function is called before it can be defined.

```
rental_car_cost(7)
def rental_car_cost(days):
  cost = days * 40
  if days >= 7:
    cost -= 50

  elif days >= 3:
    cost -= 20

return cost
```

Below Code snippet will give us the correct output.

```
def rental_car_cost(days):
  cost = days * 40
  if days >= 7:
    cost -= 50

  elif days >= 3:
    cost -= 20

return cost
rental_car_cost(7)
```